# How to fix corrupted translog in a dockerized elasticsearch instance

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

***tl;dr: Running the elasticsearch-shard utility when your ElasticSearch instance is dockerized does not seem possible. If this is true how can we fix the occasional corrupted translog errors that crash ES??***

I have had ElasticSearch (ES) running nicely locally via docker using docker-compose for some time now, but today when I started it up it started crashing with the error message:

`TranslogCorruptedException[translog from source [/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/indices/0eNM-3niSvS0BUwAHf9M0w/0/translog/translog-175.tlog] is corrupted` 
(see end of post for full error message)

Some googling revealed that this issue can be solved by running the utility `bin/elasticsearch-shard remove-corrupted-data`. The problem is that in order to run this utility ES must be shut down, but in order for the container that is hosting the ES instance to be alive ES needs to be running. This means that there is no way to have access to `elasticsearch-shard` to fix the issue inside of the environment where the data and the elasticsearch instance actually lives.

I have verified that it wont stay alive by stopping ES from within the command line of the container like so

```
## get into the docker container
docker exec -it 43146ff2a50c bash
## kill elasticsearch
pkill -f elasticsearch
```

and it immediately kills the container and kicks me out of the shell.

I tried to see if another docker container with access to the same data volumes but not based on an ES image (so that it could be alive while ES is off) could run the utility and fix the data on disk. I made a new docker-compose entry with a new Dockerfile and kept all the settings the same, but based the build on an ubuntu image (ignore the environment variables except `ES_01_DATA_VOLUME`, they aren't relevant):

***docker-compose.yml***

```
 es01-truncate-corrupted-shards:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Elasticsearch.TruncateCorruptedShards.Dockerfile
            args:
                - CERTS_DIR=${CERTS_DIR}
        container_name: es01-truncate-corrupted-shards
        environment:
            - node.name=es01
            - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
            - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
            - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
            - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
            - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
            - xpack.license.self_generated.type=basic 
            - xpack.security.enabled=true
            - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true 
            - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.key
            - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
            - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.crt
            - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true 
            - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate 
            - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
            - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.crt
            - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.key
        ulimits:
            memlock:
                soft: -1
                hard: -1
        volumes:
            - ${ES_01_DATA_VOLUME}
            - ${CERTS_VOLUME}
        ports:
            - ${ES_01_PORT}
        mem_limit: ${SINGLE_NODE_MEM_LIMIT}
```

***Elasticsearch.TruncateCorruptedShards.Dockerfile***

```
FROM ubuntu:rolling

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --yes curl \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg \
    && curl -fsSL https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list \
    && apt update \
    && apt install elasticsearch

RUN /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-shard remove-corrupted-data
```

When i run this it installs everything correctly and attempts to use the utility, but then errors like so:

```
#6 1.265     WARNING: Elasticsearch MUST be stopped before running this tool.
#6 1.265
#6 1.360 Exception in thread "main" ElasticsearchException[no node folder is found in data folder(s), node has not been started yet?]
#6 1.363    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.coordination.ElasticsearchNodeCommand.processDataPaths(ElasticsearchNodeCommand.java:148)
#6 1.363    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.coordination.ElasticsearchNodeCommand.execute(ElasticsearchNodeCommand.java:168)
#6 1.363    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:77)
#6 1.363    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:112)
#6 1.363    at org.elasticsearch.cli.MultiCommand.execute(MultiCommand.java:95)
#6 1.363    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:112)
#6 1.363    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:77)
#6 1.363    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.ShardToolCli.main(ShardToolCli.java:24)
```

which leads me to believe that despite having access to the `ES_01_DATA_VOLUME` volume it knows that an instance hasn't been set up in this container.

Ultimately I'm not too concerned with how the corrupted translog gets fixed as long as its possible, but it seems to me with these constraints of the docker environments its not possible. Do i need to install ES on the host machine and point it towards the data files and have it modify them? Seems like that is the same idea as the second non-ES container trick that I tried and so will fail. Also, that defeats the purpose of the containerized environment.

I am stumped and would be so grateful for any help. It's hard to imagine that fixing something like corrupted data files wouldn't be possible / be overlooked by the ES team!

***Full error message from ES***:

```
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-07-28T22:40:49,356Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.i.c.IndicesClusterStateService", "cluster.name": "es-docker-cluster", "node.name": "es01", "message": "[application_log][0] marking and sending shard failed due to [shard failure, reason [failed to recover from translog]]", "cluster.uuid": "W-cXJOamQw-XU8LyZ9ZUoA", "node.id": "SBUMvZCRRTaZvhhVqmm9sQ" ,
es01     | "stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.index.engine.EngineException: failed to recover from translog",
```

and

```
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-07-28T22:40:49,361Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService", "cluster.name": "es-docker-cluster", "node.name": "es03", "message": "failing shard [failed shard, shard [plant_pod_application_log][0], node[SBUMvZCRRTaZvhhVqmm9sQ], [P], recovery_source[existing store recovery; bootstrap_history_uuid=false], s[INITIALIZING], a[id=_fVgJKMpSymo_mGd-QvRxQ], unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2022-07-28T22:40:46.444Z], failed_attempts[4], failed_nodes[[VqFl_rNTRnyoHHgVJdIBhQ, SBUMvZCRRTaZvhhVqmm9sQ]], delayed=false, details[failed shard on node [VqFl_rNTRnyoHHgVJdIBhQ]: failed recovery, failure RecoveryFailedException[[plant_pod_application_log][0]: Recovery failed on {es03}{VqFl_rNTRnyoHHgVJdIBhQ}{qLLppr6pTrCa8-lCFhz1NA}{172.22.0.5}{172.22.0.5:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=5175267328, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}]; nested: IndexShardRecoveryException[failed to recover from gateway]; nested: EngineException[failed to recover from translog]; nested: TranslogCorruptedException[translog from source [/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/indices/0eNM-3niSvS0BUwAHf9M0w/0/translog/translog-187.tlog] is corrupted, translog truncated]; nested: EOFException[read past EOF. pos [16592762] length: [4] end: [16592762]]; ], allocation_status[fetching_shard_data]], message [shard failure, reason [failed to recover from translog]], failure [EngineException[failed to recover from translog]; nested: TranslogCorruptedException[translog from source [/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/indices/0eNM-3niSvS0BUwAHf9M0w/0/translog/translog-175.tlog] is corrupted, translog truncated]; nested: EOFException[read past EOF. pos [16592762] length: [4] end: [16592762]]; ], markAsStale [true]]", "cluster.uuid": "W-cXJOamQw-XU8LyZ9ZUoA", "node.id": "VqFl_rNTRnyoHHgVJdIBhQ" ,
es03     | "stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.index.engine.EngineException: failed to recover from translog",
```

I know that these are listed as WARNINGs, but they are the only type of wrong looking output and when I ping the cluster to check its health I get this payload:

```
{"cluster_name":"es-docker-cluster","status":"red","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":3,"number_of_data_nodes":3,"active_primary_shards":20,"active_shards":30,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":2,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_number":93.75
```

As well as Kibana not loading and results forever

Comment: I'd be more inclined to understand what's causing the corruption, cause I don't think there's an easy solution for your approach

Comment: @MarkWalkom it seems that according to ES this is a known thing that happens. In their documentation they say `In some cases the Lucene index or translog of a shard copy can become corrupted`, and then say that you run this utility to solve it. See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-tool.html

Comment: it's a known issue but it should be a rarity to recover from a pretty major issue, not something you need to build a procedure for to run when you run your container

Comment: Okay so you think it makes sense to try and perform some one-off manual cleanup or similar to just resolve the issue this one time, and assume i wont really run into this again? I have been trying to figure out if i can just wipe the data on my local machine that gets mounted to `/usr/share/elasticsearch/data` (the env variable `ES_01_DATA_VOLUME`) but i'm not sure if that will have unforeseen consequences. There aren't really any logs worth saving there but i don't want my configuration / user accounts to get messed up

Comment: if you wipe the data then you need to set things up again, as it deletes everything stored in Elasticsearch. but yes, assume this isn't something you should need to be running except on rare occasions

Answer (score 0):

7 months late, but I'm currently using a docker instance to try and fix a bunch of corrupt indices outside the cluster and was running into the same - so I'm documenting for posterity as well as future me running into this again :-)

The fix is simple: you run the container, but you override the entrypoint. That is to say, you add `-it` to the switches (interactive container), and you add `/bin/bash` after the image name. That way you'll end up in a freshly started container in the bash shell instead of running ES.

You can then start ES by running `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh` and kill it with ctrl-C, and you'll land in the bash shell again. The container won't exit until you exit bash, so you're now free to run elasticearch-shard or whatever tool you need, start ES again to call the routing API etc.

And, something I ran into: run elasticsearch-shard as the elasticsearch user, because if you run it as root it'll create the new translog files as root and ES won't be able to reroute the shard.

Comment: I'm past this issue now but i appreciate this answer and will probably come back to it in the future when this inevitably happens again. Would you mind posting an example of exactly how you overrode the entrypoint? would that be in the Dockerfile? usually the `-it` flags are for when you run docker exec from the command line right?

Comment: Correct, and you're using them for exactly the same reason: -i to make it interactive and -t to allocate a TTY - because you need somewhere _to_ interact :-p